# Is there way to get the Text view in other class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

**Hi there i am i want to get text of Text view the text view is defiened in 
one class and  i am accessing the textView text in othere class but i am facing the null pointer exception here so is there sollution to get this value in android.**

**the code is**

```
  String tp=new PlaceOrder().totalprze.getText().toString();
```

**and the Exception is**

```
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at student.briyani.cartAdapter$1.onClick(cartAdapter.java:125)
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-30 13:04:01.759: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If they are both `Activity` classes then use an `Intent`, or store the text to somewhere more persistent like `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
String tp=new PlaceOrder().totalprze.getText().toString();
```

`totalprze` causing issue because `PlaceOrder` is not running and doing it in wrong way by creating object of a class which is extending `Activity` or `FragmentActivity`.

> Is there way to get the Text view in other class

Yes, best way is use Intent for sending data as key-value pairs in next Activity and get all data in `onCreate` method of newly started Activity.

See following post for more details:
[How do I pass data between activities in Android?](http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/passing-data-between-activities.html)

Comment: i can use by activity but when i set data on same text then because i am using it adapter click how i will manage

Comment: @BabarAli: show code where starting new Activity on adapter click

Comment: i am not starting activity in adapter i am just notify the adapter and totalprice in my first place holder design so i can manage

Comment: @BabarAli: are you extending FragmentActivity?

Comment: @BabarAli: Then bro extends FragmentActivity

Answer (score 0):

just parse your data using intent, it will help you to doing this.

**Parsing data from one activity to another:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
i.putExtra("MyData", datatobepassed);
startActivity(i);
```

**Retrieving the data in another acivity:**

```
String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("MyData");
```

> Please, make sure that your key is same when parsing or retrieveing
>   your data.

Comment: ok i can send this by intent if i want to set back data on same text view then what again i call back actvity and then come again back this is not a proper and good solution

Comment: This is how you can parse your data using intent, another method for storing your data is to use shared preference, by which you can easily store your data in it.

Comment: If this answer helpful to you, please upvote it and like it as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there way to get the Text view in other class?

If your mean by "class" is Activity. In short, the answer is no. However, you can pass its text via several ways:

- Passing via Intent using `extra` bundle. ***`Recommended`***
- Utilizing shared Application object.
- Sending broadcasts

Otherwise, your mean by "class" is oridinary Java classes within a *same* Activity class, you should make sure that:

- You have an initialized `PlaceOrder` instance.
- Use that instance (`insPlaceOrder`, for example) for access its properties (including that `TextView`)

  ```
  String text = insPlaceOrder.totalprze.getText().toString();
  ```